# react native dynamic image slider transition opacity

Tags: react-native

I'm looking to implement in react native , slider with dynamic images with fading transition (play with opacity).
what I did is

```
     changeBackgroundImageNew = ()=>{
     const TIME_TRANSITION = 4500
    let images_length = this.props.AppStore.barbershop_details.images.length
    let index_image = 0;
    setInterval(()=>{

        if(this.state.index_image == images_length-1){
          index_image = 0
        }else{
          index_image= index_image+1
        }
        this.setState({index_image})
    },4000)
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.delay(1500),

        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(this.state.img_background_opacity, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: TIME_TRANSITION
          }),
          Animated.timing(this.state.img_background_opacity2, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: TIME_TRANSITION
          })
        ]),
        Animated.delay(1500),
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(this.state.img_background_opacity2, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: TIME_TRANSITION
          }),
          Animated.timing(this.state.img_background_opacity, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: TIME_TRANSITION
          })
        ])
      ])
    ).start(() => {
    });
  }
```

the render code

```
  {AppStore.barbershop_details && AppStore.barbershop_details.images.map((image,i)=>(
     <AnimatedImageBackground
     key={i}
     resizeMode="cover"
     resizeMethod="resize"
     style={[
       style.img_background,
       { opacity: i == this.state.index_image?this.state.img_background_opacity:this.state.img_background_opacity2 }
     ]}
     source={{uri:image}}
   />
  ))}
```

I'm trying to change the images with automatically animated fading transition,
kind of this example, but I want it in react native
[example for images transition](https://codepen.io/rajcsanyiz/pen/MbNZVV)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel)

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Carousel, { ParallaxImage } from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet,View,Text } from 'react-native';

const { width: screenWidth } = Dimensions.get('window')

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      entries: [
        {
          "ID": "001", 
          "Name": "001", 
          "thumbnail": "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/KaNO7Ya.jpg"
      },

      {
          "ID": "002", 
          "Name": "002", 
          "thumbnail": "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ZxV8qRo.jpg"
      },

      {
          "ID": "003", 
          "Name": "003", 
          "thumbnail": "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ytM5xOy.jpg"
      }
      ,

      {
          "ID": "004", 
          "Name": "004", 
          "thumbnail": "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/STgHPst.jpg"
      }
      ,

      {
          "ID": "005", 
          "Name": "005", 
          "thumbnail": "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/vg5q7pY.jpg"
      }
      ,

      {
          "ID": "006", 
          "Name": "006", 
          "thumbnail": "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/b2HsGgL.jpg"
      }
      ],
  }
}
    _renderItem ({item, index}, parallaxProps) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.item}>
                <ParallaxImage
                    source={{ uri: item.thumbnail }}
                    containerStyle={styles.imageContainer}
                    style={styles.image}
                    parallaxFactor={0.4}
                    {...parallaxProps}
                />
                <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={2}>
                    { item.Name }
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render () {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Carousel
                sliderWidth={screenWidth}
                sliderHeight={screenWidth}
                itemWidth={screenWidth - 60}
                data={this.state.entries}
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
                hasParallaxImages={true}
            />
          </View>

        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    marginTop:50
  },  
  item: {
    width: screenWidth - 60,
    height: screenWidth - 60,
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginBottom: Platform.select({ ios: 0, android: 1 }), // Prevent a random Android rendering issue
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  image: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
})
```

Output:

https://gph.is/g/ZdoYdWw

You can play with this component and get your desired output rather than creating your own custom component. You can create your custom image container and also set fade duration, etc. For more details, go through with its documentation.

English is not my mother language; please excuse any errors on my part.

Comment: Hey, I don't want to use in package such snap-carousel.. it's not what I'm looking for.. it's not make the fade effect.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code as per your example:

try with `View` tag style `backgroundColor:'#5f9ea0',//change color` and without Image set background for it.

```
imoprt { ScrollView, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

render(){
let screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
let screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

return(
    <ScrollView
        horizontal={true}
        pagingEnabled= {true}
        showHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
    >
        <View style={{          
            flex:1,
            marginTop:20,
            width: screenWidth,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        }}>
                <Image source={} style={{ flex: 1, resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'}} />

                // add your UI code for create like 
                <Text> Screen 1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{          
            flex:1,
            marginTop:20,
            width: screenWidth,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        }}>
                <Image source={} style={{ flex: 1, resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'}} />

                // add your UI code for create like 
                <Text> Screen 2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{          
            flex:1,
            marginTop:20,
            width: screenWidth,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        }}>
                <Image source={} style={{ flex: 1, resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'}} />

                // add your UI code for create like 
                <Text> Screen 3</Text>
        </View>



);

}
```

I hope it will help you. On fad Effect see the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2B0vVIHV_A

Comment: Hey, not. it's not fade effect and not scroll automatic

Comment: I'll try and reply you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

try used this package react-native-image-slider-show hear example [example for how to used it](https://github.com/kamalpandey/react-native-image-slider-show)